# Edit a file in two different terminal windows

Tags: neovim, buffers, vim-windows, split, window-management

It's nice to edit the same file from two different views.  I use a vsplit for this, as described [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/is-it-possible-to-simultaneously-edit-one-file-in-two-views), and it works well.

However, I'd like to have the two views open in different terminal windows, because I use a tiling window manager, and I've already got the muscle memory to switch between two open `vim`s using the window manager's hotkeys.  Also, it's easier to tell which one is focused, because I've set un-focused windows to become transparent.

I can open the same file twice, but then changes don't propagate from one process to the other until I save.

Comment: You might be able to get away with `autoread` and such, but it's unlikely to be perfect. You'll have fewer issues with a single Vim instance, or with one write and one readonly instance.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the [linked Question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/is-it-possible-to-simultaneously-edit-one-file-in-two-views) & that [Answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/is-it-possible-to-simultaneously-edit-one-file-in-two-views/19197#19197) , we can see more about what you want :

```
Summary:  
   A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.  
   A window is a viewport on a buffer.  
   A tab page is a collection of windows.
```

In your Case , the two terminals are 2 GUI Processes (eg `xterm`) , running 2 Shells (eg `bash`) which are running 2 `vi` Processes.
The 2 `vi` Processes DO NOT SHARE the in-memory text of a file.

Hence what you want is currently not Possible.
It may become Possible if (& when) `vi` gets the functionality to share the in-memory text of a file , eg through some IPC or memory mapping , though that would be buggy.